# How to create the custom Calendar in LWUIT?

Tags: java-me, calendar, lwuit, codenameone

Currently in LWUIT, I can use `Calendar`. But I can't add the notes on particular dates.

How to create the custom `Calendar` in LWUIT? Because I need to show the birthday notes on LWUIT `Calendar` and want to show the birthday notes when user select that particular dates. See this sample image,

[image]

Is this possible to create like above sample `Calendar` in LWUIT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can derive Calendar and override:

```
protected void updateButtonDayDate(Button dayButton, int currentMonth, int day);
```

Here you can effectively customize the button in any way you choose starting by setting a UIID or anything like that.

If you want to add basic features to the button via inheritance you can override:

```
protected Button createDay();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify calendar's all the things in themes / designer, including color, font etc.

[image]

Just add appropriate component..

Thanks, Akash